# gem install compass error after Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 update

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, gruntjs, compass

A few days ago I did a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 Security Update 2018-005. Yesterday I ran grunt and got a:

```
Warning: Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: spawn sass ENOENT Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/appseed-io/supermodular/issues/45

```
xcode-select --install
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

I was still getting grunt errors:

```
Running "sass:build" (sass) task
ERROR: Cannot load compass.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I then followed the instruction here: https://halfelf.org/2017/grunt-cant-build-sass-on-high-sierra/

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

rbenv install 2.4.2
rbenv global 2.4.2

sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```

Still getting the grunt `ERROR: Cannot load compass.`

Then tried `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass` again, but get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I checked the mkmf.log file which says:

```
"pkg-config --exists libffi"
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin16 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L.             -L /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

What I take from that (not really knowing) is that `package configuration for libffi is not found` and `fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found`.

Additional info:

Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

sass -v
Sass 3.4.25 (Selective Steve)

compass -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/compass: 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I ran `gem env`. This is the output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/username/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin
     - /Users/username/.wp-cli/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: paste the output of the following. `gem env`.  It sounds like your `$PATH` is not setup correctly, this is often the problem with `rbenv`.

Comment: Thanks @lacostenycoder. I updated the question with the `gem env` output.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Seems like it's trying to find compass in a different directory than where ruby is not installed. How can I correct `$PATH`?

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass`

The whole point of using `rbenv` is to let it handle all of your dependencies and not have to deal at all with your OS system ruby or it's gems.  You need to get your `$PATH` configuration right and then you won't need to ever use `sudo` in fact you should NOT with `gem install` or any `gem` commands after getting your environment setup correctly.

Did you happen to try `npm install -g grunt-cli` ?

UPDATE: as expect your $PATH is not correct.

Close all terminals.  Start a new one.  Then run this.

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

This should help you figure out what's wrong in your `$PATH` setting.
Refer to https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

But first specifically try:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then restart your terminal and check `gem env` again and see if your path includes `.rbenv`

If these steps don't get you working then I suggest to [fully uninstall](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv) rbenv and start over from step 1 of https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on `rbenv`. I tried `npm install -g grunt-cli` but getting same `ERROR: Cannot load compass.`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I updated the `$PATH` setting. Then was able to run `gem update --system` then `gem install compass` and now grunt compiles.

Comment: Great!  Did you end up having to reinstall `rbenv` or just updated your `$PATH` ?

Comment: No, didn't have to reinstall `rbenv`. I hadn't set it up correctly to begin with. rbenv-doctor said to run `rbenv init` then add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to .bash_profile. Then I added `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` like you said. And then it all worked!